# Get json object in java

Tags: java, json, object

At client side, I send array to sever

```
plan = []
plan.push
  name: "base"
  value: base
plan.push
  name: "detail"
  value: detail    
$.ajax
  type: "POST"
  url: "/plan"
  dataType: "json"
  ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  data: plan
  success:(data) ->
    alert data
```

At server side, I get

```
"base":["[object Object]"],"result":["[object Object]"]
```

How I can get data of Object(base":["[object Object]"])????

Comment: What are `base` and `detail`?

Comment: `[object Object]` indicates that your javascript object was not JSON serialized...

Comment: base and detail which contain data. If data is : {"base":["term":"1","updated":"04/23/2013"}],detail:[{a:1},{b:2}]}. How can I get these object(base,detail)???

Comment: Please allow the OP to clarify the server-side technology. There are two issues currently, one is serializing correctly, the other is how to handle it on the server, which may or may not be Java or JavaScript.

Comment: I want to send a json Object from. At server side - Java - I want to get it.

Comment: @DuongTranAnhThoai On the server side, use any JSON parsing library, e.g., [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or similar. On the client side, it looks like there's still a serialization issue.